How to print lines starting with semicolon using batch script?
I have the following lines in a text file
LOG FILE

;Serial

;USB

;Network

I want to print all the lines using a batch script, I tried the following solution but it does not print lines starting with semicolon
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in ("input.txt") do (
    set "line=%%i"
    echo !line!
)

endlocal


Hi @add Use the command TYPE input.txt to achieve your objective.

This question is similar to: Batch files: How to read a file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The task you have laid out in your question could be achieved using just the following:
@Type "P:\athTo\input.txt"
@Pause

If you have a specific, yet withheld, reason, for using a For loop, the important thing to remember is that any beginning End Of Line starting with a semicolon is ignored. You can overcome that by selecting another end of line character, (which you know not to exist at line starts), or as below, no end of line character:
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

If Exist "input.txt" For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("input.txt") Do (
    Set "line=%%G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo !line!
    EndLocal
)

Pause
EndLocal

If you want the lines containing nothing too, then you'd need to make changes. A standard For /F loop ignores such lines, so you'd need to force them using the line numbering feature of findstr.exe or find.exe, (as below):
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

If Exist "input.txt" For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /N
 /V "" 0^<"input.txt"') Do (Set "line=%%G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo(!line:*]=!
    EndLocal
)

Pause
EndLocal


Provided the semicolon is indeed the first character of the Line, and not the first non white-space character, there may also be used:
@echo off
If exist "input.txt" %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^;" "input.txt"


T3RR0R, the question is explicit, "I want to print all the lines using a batch script". You have seemingly misunderstood it to mean, "I want to print all the lines which begin with a semicolon". Their problem was just that their For loop "does not print lines starting with semicolon".

@Compo I have interpreted in accordance with the question title.

Not only does the title not say "How to print only lines starting with semicolon using batch script?", you are experienced enough to read the body of the question along side it, T3RR0R. I was simply giving you a courtesy heads up to prevent any future downvotes, it is your choice whether you decide to heed it.
